# undefined function???  when accessing SharePoint from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I use js to retrieve one list in Sharepoint. The code is below:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getInnerHTML, "sp.js");

function getInnerHTML(){
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    this.site = ctx.get_site(); 
    this.web = ctx.get_web();
    ctx.load(this.web); 
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFail)); 
}
```

but it reported: getInnerHTML() is undefined

what??? I defined and declared it in the head, what can I do!?!?!

Comment: have you included SP.js?

Comment: ya!   ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getInnerHTML, "sp.js");

Comment: getInnerHTML() is the function I wrote

Comment: where did you place ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded()?

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code to see where the code breaks?

Comment: out of the function, at the top of javascript

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the function before using it.

```
function getInnerHTML(){
    // ...
}

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getInnerHTML, "sp.js");
```